# Data-driven approach to networking in C. This can't be new?

Tags: c, networking, data-driven

I'd like to know whether something like this has been done before:

I've recently started work on a networking library in C. The library maintains a set of sockets, each of which is associated with two FIFO byte streams, input and output.

A developer using the library is expected to register some callbacks, consisting of a recognizer function and a handler function. If new data arrives on a socket (i.e. the input stream), every recognizer is called. If one of the recognizers finds a matching portion of data, its associated handler is called, consuming the data and possibly queuing new data on the socket's output stream, scheduled to be transmitted later on.

Here's an example to make clear how the library is used:

```
// create client socket
client = nc_create(NC_CLIENT);

// register some callback functions that you'll have to supply yourself
nc_register_callback(client, &is_login, &on_login);
nc_register_callback(client, &is_password, &on_password);

// connect to server
nc_dial(client, "www.google.com", "23");

// start main loop (we might as well have more than one connection here)
nc_talk();
```

To me, this is the most obvious way to write a general purpose networking library in C. I did some research using Google, but I wasn't able to find something similar written in C. But it's hard to believe that I'm the first one that implements this approach.

**Are there other data-driven general purpose C networking libraries like this out there?

Would you use them?**

Comment: I don't know of a library that does it, but I've written this same code before as part of a multiprotocol VoIP system. The trouble I ran into is that the detectors need to be light weight since they all run on every packet, but some of them end up needing to be complex and stateful. (Eg, a detector which tries to determine if a given input packet is RTP, you can only get so far by analysing the packet itself in isolation, to really be certain you need to analyse the entire stream to see if Seq and SSRCs work out, or maybe even need a SIP/SDP packet to know what kind of data the packet contains

Comment: @bdk: Thanks for your comment! You're right, I've noticed that too. The approach described in my posting is probably best suitable for stateless conversation-like protocols: SMTP, POP3, IMAP, IRC, telnet etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few libraries that provides similar APIs, (at various levels, e.g. libevent provides a general callback driven API for socket/file descriptors)

[libesmtp](http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/) ([example](http://libesmtp.sourcearchive.com/lines/1.0.4-4/mail-file_8c-source.html))

[libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html)

The Sun/[OncRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) APIs have a similar style, in that the library does the heavy lifting for you, dispatching requests to the proper callback handlers.

The Java [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) and [mina](http://mina.apache.org/client-architecture.html) libraries works in a similar manner, although more object oriented.

Comment: libesmtp (SMTP) and libcurl (file transfer) don't qualify as being general-purpose libraries, but libevent looks very promising. At first sight, I like its API. Thanks for the hint!